# Are the Sokovia Accords still in effect?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

After the events at the end of *Infinity War*, **are there any indications in the films that the Sokovia Accords are still in effect?**

When we catch up with the Avengers a few years later (in *Endgame*), they seem to be just running themselves. Was anything put into place by the writers that didn't make it into the film(s) that could have revealed this?

Comment: My guess would be that after the snap half of the people who had been directing that project were dead and it kind of fell apart.

Comment: *"World governments are in pieces"* is the line. I suspect that goes for whoever's in charge of policing the Sokovia accords.

Comment: The UN made the Sokovia Accords and as we saw they were focused on the whole Blip and GRC thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### No.

The Sokovia Accords were repealed prior to the events of *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* season 1, episode 8, "Ribbit and Rip it", which took place in the summer of 2025, according to *Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*. In that episode, Matt Murdock makes this statement in court, while representing a client in a case:

> **Matt Murdock:** The very nature of Mr. Jacobson's line of work, making suits exclusively for superheroes, necessitates anonymity. May I remind you that the Sokovia Accords have been repealed.

[image: page of the official timeline showing when the above episode took place]

In *Avengers: Endgame,* the Sokovia Accords were still in effect, and they remained so until at least the fall of 2023. That’s when the events of *WandaVision* season 1, episode 5, “On a Very Special Episode…” took place, according to the official timeline. In this episode, FBI agent Jimmy Woo reveals that Wanda Maximoff broke the law when she apparently did this:

> **Tyler Hayward:** Nine days ago. Maximoff stormed our facility, stole the Vision's body, and resurrected him.
> **Jimmy Woo:** But that's in direct violation of Section 36 B of the Sokovia Accords.

Answer (score 8):

**They are likely still technically in effect, but are largely irrelevant**

The Avengers don't seem to really exist as an entity any more, five years after the snap. Iron Man has retired to raise a family, Thor sits around getting drunk and playing video games all day. Hawkeye has become a loner vigilante, and Hulk seems to have become pretty nonviolent (plus he spent a long time shut away, "fixing" his condition).

In Black Widow's holographic conference call, we see:

- Okoye, who is not subject to the Sokovia accords: She's the commander of the Wakandan military, not an Avenger.
- Rocket, Nebula, and Captain Marvel, all of whose actions are somewhat out of the jurisdiction of the Sokovia accords.
- War Machine, who works for the US military and is presumably acting under their authority.

That leaves Black Widow and Captain America. They were both fugitives as of *Infinity War*, and there's been no indication that status has changed. However, it seems incredibly likely that, with the world in shambles after the snap, there are no government agencies spending resources on actively pursuing them - there are a huge number of higher priorities for them to deal with.

It's reasonable to assume that most people in power are happier with Cap and Widow out there, doing their best to maintain some semblance of peace and order. So even if they are technically still wanted, in practice they probably have a lot of leeway in their operations.